# Where Statement Within Inner-Join

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to select info from our customers most recent purchase or abandonment and getting an error message at the Where statement.

```
SELECT Orders.EMAILADDRESS as EMAILADDRESS, [All Productions].REGIONID, [All Productions].EVENTTYPE, [All Productions].EVENTCATEGORY, [All Productions].EVENTNAME
FROM Orders INNER JOIN [All Productions]
WHERE Orders.ORDERDATE = (
     Select MAX(Orders.ORDERDATE)
     FROM Orders
     GROUP BY EMAILADDRESS
)
ON Orders. PRODUCTIONID = [All Productions].PRODUCTIONID

UNION
SELECT Carts.EMAILADDRESS as EMAILADDRESS, [All Productions].REGIONID, [All Productions].EVENTTYPE, [All Productions].EVENTCATEGORY, [All Productions].EVENTNAME
FROM Orders INNER JOIN [All Productions]
WHERE Carts.ABANDONDATE = (
     Select MAX(Carts.ABANDONDATE)
     FROM Carts
     GROUP BY EMAILADDRESS
)
ON Carts.ABANDONDID = [All Productions].PRODUCTIONID
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Probably, your subqueries used in WHERE clause return multiple results.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.  What database are you using?

Comment: Fix Order of ON and WHERE with ensuring single result from subquery

Answer (score 2):

Join `ON` condition should come before the `where` clause

```
SELECT Orders.EMAILADDRESS AS EMAILADDRESS,
       [All Productions].REGIONID,
       [All Productions].EVENTTYPE,
       [All Productions].EVENTCATEGORY,
       [All Productions].EVENTNAME
FROM   Orders
       INNER JOIN [All Productions]
               ON Orders. PRODUCTIONID = [All Productions].PRODUCTIONID
       JOIN (SELECT Max(Orders.ORDERDATE) ORDERDATE,
                    EMAILADDRESS
             FROM   Orders
             GROUP  BY EMAILADDRESS) B
         ON Orders.ORDERDATE = B.ORDERDATE
            AND Orders.EMAILADDRESS = b.EMAILADDRESS
UNION
SELECT Carts.EMAILADDRESS AS EMAILADDRESS,
       [All Productions].REGIONID,
       [All Productions].EVENTTYPE,
       [All Productions].EVENTCATEGORY,
       [All Productions].EVENTNAME
FROM   Orders
       INNER JOIN [All Productions]
               ON Carts.ABANDONDID = [All Productions].PRODUCTIONID
       JOIN (SELECT Max(Carts.ABANDONDATE),EMAILADDRESS
             FROM   Carts
             GROUP  BY EMAILADDRESS) b
         ON b.ABANDONDATE = Carts.ABANDONDATE
            AND Orders.EMAILADDRESS = b.EMAILADDRESS
```

Comment: This will produce an error if there is more than one email address.

Comment: @RonSmith - yeah missed the group by. Updated now

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `where` goes after `on` (`on` is part of the `from` clause; the `where` clause follows the `from` clause).  So the structure of the query is not correct.

Even if you fixed the syntax, you have a second problem; the query would return an error, because the subquery would -- in all likelihood -- return more than one row.  The first is what you seem to be trying to do with the first subquery:

```
SELECT o.EMAILADDRESS as EMAILADDRESS, ap.REGIONID,
       ap.EVENTTYPE, [All Productions].EVENTCATEGORY,
       ap.EVENTNAME
FROM Orders as o INNER JOIN
     [All Productions] as ap
     ON o.PRODUCTIONID = ap.PRODUCTIONID
WHERE o.ORDERDATE = (Select MAX(o2.ORDERDATE)
                     FROM Orders as o2
                     WHERE o2.EMAILADDRESS = o.EMAILADRESS
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `row_number` function to get the latest date for each grouping:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT
        Orders.EMAILADDRESS as EMAILADDRESS,
        [All Productions].REGIONID,
        [All Productions].EVENTTYPE,
        [All Productions].EVENTCATEGORY,
        [All Productions].EVENTNAME,
        row_number() over(partition by Orders.EMAILADDRESS
                          order by Orders.ORDERDATE desc) as LATEST
    FROM Orders
        INNER JOIN [All Productions]
            ON Orders. PRODUCTIONID = [All Productions].PRODUCTIONID
    UNION
    SELECT
        Carts.EMAILADDRESS as EMAILADDRESS,
        [All Productions].REGIONID,
        [All Productions].EVENTTYPE,
        [All Productions].EVENTCATEGORY,
        [All Productions].EVENTNAME,
        row_number() over(partition by Carts.EMAILADDRESS
                          order by Carts.ORDERDATE desc) as LATEST
    FROM Carts
        INNER JOIN [All Productions]
            ON Carts.ABANDONDID = [All Productions].PRODUCTIONID)
WHERE LATEST = 1
```